# How can I create a log table in data base which contain all Django operations that have been failed

Tags: python, django, django-models, backend

I am pretty new in Django , and I try to make a log table which contain all the bad operations like :
UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE and the reason it has been failed , for example : unique field is already exist.
I tried to do it with Signals, pre_post but when an error occur,it even doesn't get into my create() function on my serializer .
any ideas ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Django has already created the ability to execute logging which you can find at the link below:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/logging/#

Sounds like in order to do what you want, you should be able to create your own handler and have specific logs loaded to the DB.

Comment: Thank for you comment, Sorry that I didn't explain my self well, I work with serializer that make all the response for me so I dont know exactly where can I handle this error , and use with the logging

Comment: I think if you use the request logging extension you should be able to capture issues with inbound requests which ultimately is what serializers help to accomplish.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/logging/#django-request